# ValidationException when @Autowired-ing a DAO

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I'm trying to add JPA support for my app however, I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 37 more
```

Although I have these jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder:

```
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain, but my best guess is that `validation-api` is not actually an *implementation* of validation, so you still need to include one such as [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Comment: I'm not sure why do I need to add Hibernate jar in my app if I am not using any Hibernate in my code, I mean I ma using GAE. Is this the only work-around?

Comment: Tried adding hibernate validator yet still getting the same error.

Comment: Make sure it's at least Hibernate validator 4, and includes all the dependencies such as hibernate-validator-annotation-processor (if you use Maven this should happen automatically). Also you may want to try adding a bean such as `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />`